# Jekyll get specific _data data based on an name

Tags: jekyll

I have a data folder structure:

`_data/footer/1.yml`
`_data/footer/2.yml` etc

What I want to do is within the template, based on the front matter variable is to, select one of those files and return the data contained in them.

If I do this:
`site.data.footer.1` it returns the data withn 1.yml. If I try to do `site.data.footer.{{page.footer}}` it returns nothing, even if the front matter has the footer variable set to 1 like this:

```
---
footer: 1
---
{% assign foot_id = page.footer %}
{{foot_id}}
{% assign stuff = site.data.footer.{{foot_id}} %}
{{stuff}}
```

`stuff` in this case would be blank. Is this the correct way to do this? Whats going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we look at your datas :

```
site.data.footer = {"1"=>{"variable"=>"one"}, "2"=>{"variable"=>"two"}}
```

we have a hash were keys are strings.

We can access our datas like this :

```
{{ site.data.footer.1 }} => {"variable"=>"one"}
or
{{ site.data.footer["1"] }} => {"variable"=>"one"}
```

Note that the bracket notation takes a string as key. If you try with an integer, it returns nothing `{{ site.data.footer[1] }} => null`.

If we want to use a `page` variable, we need it to be a string. It can be :

```
---
# a string in the front matter
footer: "1"
---

{{ site.data.footer[page.footer] }} => {"variable"=>"one"}
```

or an integer casted to string

```
---
# a string in the front matter
footer: 1 
---

Transform an integer to a string by adding it an empty string
{% assign foot_id = page.footer | append: "" %}

{{ site.data.footer[foot_id] }} => {"variable"=>"one"}
```

Note: you can also cast a string to an integer like this :

```
{% assign my_integer = "1" | plus: 0 %}
{{ my_integer | inspect }} => 1 but not "1"
```